Why is my Android JetPack Compose dependency not found?
I am starting the process of converting an existing android only app to Kotlin MultiPlatform.  I have started with a shell application using the Android Studio wizard to create a multi-platform project. I am carrying over the gradle dependencies from the current app to the new project. Once I get the gradle builds working correctly, I will be transferring common logic from the old app to the new KMP project.
Any assistance you can provide will be greatly appreciated.
When running the gradle build, I get the following error. Not sure where the reference to iosArm64Main is coming from either.
 :shared:iosArm64Main: Could not resolve androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.6.8.
Required by:
    project :shared
    project :shared > androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.06.00

The following is my settings.gradle file
enableFeaturePreview("TYPESAFE_PROJECT_ACCESSORS")
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url = uri("https://jitpack.io")
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
            flatDir {
                dirs("libs")
                dirs("app/libs")
            }
        }

    }
}

rootProject.name = "My_Application"
include(":androidApp")
include(":shared")
include(":app")
include(":ksp")
include("ksp-annotation")
include("ksp-processor")

The following is my project level build.gradle file.
plugins {
    
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroid).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.com.google.devtools.ksp).apply(false)

}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        configurations.configureEach {
            maven {
                url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
            }
            maven {
                url = uri("https://jitpack.io")
            }
            maven {
                url = uri("https://maven.google.com/")
            }
            resolutionStrategy {
                force("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0")
            }
        }
    }
}

The following is my app level build.gradle (for the shared directory)
 plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidx.room)
    alias(libs.plugins.com.google.devtools.ksp)
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            //put your multiplatform dependencies here
            implementation(projects.shared)

            implementation (libs.android)

            //Compose

            val composeBom =
                project.dependencies.platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.06.00")
            implementation(composeBom)
            implementation(libs.compose.ui)
            implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
            implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)

            // UI Tests
            implementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
            //debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)

            // Optional - Integration with activities
            implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose.v190)
            // Optional - Integration with ViewModels
            implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose)
            // Optional - Integration with LiveData
            implementation(libs.androidx.runtime.livedata)

            implementation (libs.androidx.core.ktx)
            implementation (libs.androidx.coordinatorlayout)
            implementation (libs.compose.material3)
            implementation (libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx.v283)
            implementation (libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)
            implementation (libs.kotlinx.coroutines.android)
            implementation (libs.android)
            implementation (libs.com.google.firebase.firebase.appcheck.debug)
            implementation (libs.com.google.firebase.firebase.appcheck.playintegrity)
            implementation (libs.billing)
            implementation (libs.androidx.work.multiprocess)
            implementation (libs.androidx.appcompat) //this
            implementation (libs.androidx.constraintlayout) //this
            implementation (libs.androidx.legacy.support.v4)
            implementation (libs.androidx.navigation.fragment.ktx)
            implementation (libs.androidx.navigation.ui.ktx)
            implementation (libs.androidx.lifecycle.extensions)
            implementation (libs.androidx.recyclerview)  //this
            implementation (libs.emoji.google.v070)
            implementation (libs.play.services.ads.v2320)
            implementation (libs.firebase.ads.v2320)
            implementation (libs.androidx.work.runtime.v290)
            implementation (libs.androidx.preference.preference.ktx)
            implementation (libs.com.google.android.gms.play.services.maps)
            implementation (libs.com.google.firebase.firebase.auth)
            implementation (libs.androidx.annotation.v180)  //this
            implementation (libs.androidx.lifecycle.livedata.ktx.v283)
            implementation (libs.com.google.firebase.firebase.database)
            implementation (libs.com.google.firebase.firebase.functions)
            implementation (libs.androidx.wear)
            implementation (libs.androidx.viewpager)

            implementation (libs.com.google.firebase.firebase.analytics)
            implementation (libs.com.google.firebase.firebase.messaging)
            implementation (libs.com.firebaseui.firebase.ui.database)
            implementation (libs.com.firebaseui.firebase.ui.auth)
            implementation (libs.com.google.android.material.material)
            implementation (libs.com.google.gms.play.services.gcm)
            implementation (libs.com.android.volley)
            implementation (libs.com.google.android.gms)
            implementation (libs.androidx.mutidex)
            implementation (libs.com.google.android.libraries.maps)
            implementation (libs.androidx.biometrics)
            implementation (libs.com.google.auto.value.annotations)
            implementation (libs.com.google.maps.android)
            implementation (libs.com.google.code.json)
            implementation (libs.com.anroidmapsextension)
            implementation(libs.materialdrawer)

            // Room components

            implementation(libs.symbol.processing.api)
            apply(plugin = "com.google.devtools.ksp")


            implementation (libs.androidx.room.compiler.v270alpha06)
            implementation (libs.androidx.room.room.runtime)
            implementation (libs.androidx.room.testing)

            implementation (libs.androidx.sqlite)
            implementation (libs.net.zetic.sqlcipher.android)
            implementation(libs.androidx.room.room.gradle.plugin)
            implementation(libs.androidx.sqlite.bundled)
            implementation (libs.androidx.sqlite.sqlite)

            // Lifecycle components
            implementation (libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime)
            implementation (libs.androidx.lifecycle.common.java8)
            implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.compiler)

            // UI
            implementation (libs.com.google.android.material.material)

            // Testing
            implementation (libs.androidx.core.testing)

            compileOnly (libs.wearable)
            implementation(files("libs/activation.jar"))
            implementation(files("libs/additionnal.jar"))
            implementation(files("libs/mail.jar"))
            implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar", "*.aar"))))

            implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
            implementation(libs.com.google.gms.google.services)
            implementation(libs.androidx.hilt.compiler)
            implementation (libs.hilt.compiler)


        }
        iosMain.dependencies {
            val composeBom =
                project.dependencies.platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.06.00")
            implementation(composeBom)
            implementation  (libs.compose.ui)
        }
        commonTest.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.grgmobilesolutions.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 34
        //applicationId = "com.grgmobilesolutions.myapplication"
        targetSdk = 34
        //versionCode = 1
        //versionName = "1.0"

    }
    configurations.implementation {
        exclude(group = "com;intellij", module = "annotations")
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.15"
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            //isShrinkResources = true
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
        getByName("debug") {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            //isShrinkResources = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }

    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
    room {
        schemaDirectory("$projectDir/schemas")
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    //kotlinOptions {
   //     jvmTarget = "1.8"
   // }
}

The following is my libs.versions.toml file
[versions]
activityCompose = "1.9.1"
agp = "8.5.2"
android = "3.2.0"
annotation = "1.8.2"
appcompat = "1.7.0"
billing = "7.0.0"
constraintlayout = "2.1.4"
coordinatorlayout = "1.2.0"
coreTesting = "2.2.0"
emojiGoogle = "0.7.0"
firebaseAds = "23.3.0"
firebaseBom = "33.1.2"
hiltCompiler = "1.2.0"
hiltCompilerVersion = "2.51.1"
kotlin = "2.0.0"
compose = "1.6.8"
compose-material3 = "1.2.1"
androidx-activityCompose = "1.9.1"
kotlinVersion = "2.0.0"
kotlinxCoroutinesAndroid = "1.8.0"
kotlinxCoroutinesCore = "1.8.0"
legacySupportV4 = "1.0.0"
lifecycleExtensions = "2.2.0"
lifecycleCompiler = "2.8.4"
lifecycleLivedataKtx = "2.8.4"
lifecycleViewmodelCompose = "2.8.4"
lifecycleViewmodelKtx = "2.8.4"
materialdrawer = "9.0.2"
navigationFragmentKtx = "2.7.7"
playServicesAds = "23.3.0"
roomCompiler = "2.7.0-alpha06"
roomVersion = "2.7.0-alpha06"
lifecycleVersion = "2.8.4"
materialVersion = "1.12.0"
recyclerviewVersion = "1.3.2"
playServicesAdsVersion =  "23.3.0"
playServicesGCMVersion =  "17.0.0"
firebaseAdsVersion = "23.3.0"
sqliteBundled = "2.5.0-alpha06"
sqliteVersion = "2.4.0"
symbolProcessingApi = "2.0.10-1.0.24"
wearable = "2.9.0"
workMultiprocess = "2.9.1"
workRuntime = "2.9.1"
workRuntimeVersion =  "2.9.1"
preferenceKTXVersion  = "1.2.1"
playServicesMapsVersion = "19.0.0"
firebaseAuthVersion = "23.0.0"
annotationVersion = "1.8.2"
lifecycleLiveDataKTXVersion = "2.8.4"
lifecycleViewModelKTXVersion = "2.8.4"
firebaseDatabaseVersion = "21.0.0"
firebaseFunctionsVersion =  "21.0.0"
wearVersion = "1.3.0"
viewpager2Version = "1.1.0"
touchImageViewVersion = "1.4.1"
firebaseBOMVersion = "33.1.2"
firebaseAnalyticsVersion = "22.0.2"
firebaseMessagingVersion = "24.0.0"
firebaseAppcheckVersion = "18.0.0"
firebaseUIDatabasse = "8.0.2"
firebaseUIAuth = "8.0.2"
volleyVersion = "1.2.1"
playServicesLocationVersion = "21.3.0"
multidexVersion = "2.0.1"
mapsVersion = "3.1.0-beta"
biometricVersion = "1.2.0-alpha05"
autoValueAnnotationsVersion = "1.10.4"
androidMapsUtilsVersion = "3.8.2"
gsonVersion = "2.10.1"
androidMapsExtensionVersion =  "2.4.0"
workRuntimeKTXVersion = "2.9.1"
roomRuntimeVersion = "2.7.0-alpha06"
roomGradlePluginVersion = "2.7.0-alpha06"
sqliteKTXVeresion  = "2.4.0"
sqlcipherAndroidVersion = "4.5.5"
vannitechVersion = "com0.7.0"
androidRoomVersion = "2.7.0-alpha06"
googleServicesVersion = "4.4.2"
androidGradlePluginVersion = "8.3.2"
kotlinMultiplatformVersion = "2.0.0"
coreKtxVersion = "1.13.1"
junitVersion = "4.13.2"
junit = "1.2.1"
espressoCoreVersion = "3.6.1"
devToolsGradlePluginVersion = "2.0.0-1.0.22"
devToolsKSPVersion = "2.6.1"
hilt_version = '2.51.1'
composeBOM = "2024.06.00"
[libraries]
androidx-compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "composeBOM" }
androidx-compose-foundation = { group = "androidx.compose.foundation", name = "foundation" }
android = { module = "com.bugfender.sdk:android", version.ref = "android" }
androidx-activity-compose-v190 = { module = "androidx.activity:activity-compose", version.ref = "activityCompose" }
androidx-annotation-v180 = { module = "androidx.annotation:annotation", version.ref = "annotation" }
androidx-appcompat = { module = "androidx.appcompat:appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
androidx-constraintlayout = { module = "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout", version.ref = "constraintlayout" }
androidx-coordinatorlayout = { module = "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout", version.ref = "coordinatorlayout" }
androidx-core-testing = { module = "androidx.arch.core:core-testing", version.ref = "coreTesting" }
androidx-hilt-compiler = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hiltCompiler" }
androidx-legacy-support-v4 = { module = "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4", version.ref = "legacySupportV4" }
androidx-lifecycle-common-java8 = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8", version.ref = "lifecycleLivedataKtx" }
androidx-lifecycle-compiler = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler", version.ref = "lifecycleCompiler" }
androidx-lifecycle-extensions = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions", version.ref = "lifecycleExtensions" }
androidx-lifecycle-livedata-ktx-v283 = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleLivedataKtx" }
androidx-lifecycle-viewmodel-compose = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose", version.ref = "lifecycleViewmodelCompose" }
androidx-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-v283 = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleViewmodelKtx" }
androidx-material3 = { module = "androidx.compose.material3:material3" }
androidx-navigation-fragment-ktx = { module = "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx", version.ref = "navigationFragmentKtx" }
androidx-navigation-ui-ktx = { module = "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx", version.ref = "navigationFragmentKtx" }
androidx-room-compiler-v270alpha06 = { module = "androidx.room:room-compiler", version.ref = "roomCompiler" }
androidx-room-testing = { module = "androidx.room:room-testing", version.ref = "roomCompiler" }
androidx-runtime-livedata = { module = "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata" }
androidx-sqlite-bundled = { module = "androidx.sqlite:sqlite-bundled", version.ref = "sqliteBundled" }
androidx-sqlite-sqlite = { module = "androidx.sqlite:sqlite", version.ref = "sqliteVersion" }
androidx-ui-test-junit4 = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4" }
androidx-ui-test-manifest = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest" }
androidx-ui-tooling = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling" }
androidx-ui-tooling-preview = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview" }
androidx-work-multiprocess = { module = "androidx.work:work-multiprocess", version.ref = "workMultiprocess" }
androidx-work-runtime-v290 = { module = "androidx.work:work-runtime", version.ref = "workRuntime" }
billing = { module = "com.android.billingclient:billing", version.ref = "billing" }
emoji-google-v070 = { module = "com.vanniktech:emoji-google", version.ref = "emojiGoogle" }
firebase-ads-v2320 = { module = "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads", version.ref = "firebaseAds" }
firebase-bom-v3311 = { module = "com.google.firebase:firebase-bom", version.ref = "firebaseBom" }
hilt-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hiltCompilerVersion" }
kotlin-test = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test", version.ref = "kotlin" }
compose-ui = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui", version.ref = "compose" }
compose-ui-tooling = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling", version.ref = "compose" }
compose-ui-tooling-preview = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview", version.ref = "compose" }
compose-foundation = { module = "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation", version.ref = "compose" }
compose-material3 = { module = "androidx.compose.material3:material3", version.ref = "compose-material3" }
androidx-recyclerview = {group = "androidx.recyclerview", name = "recyclerview", version.ref = "recyclerviewVersion"}
com-vannitech = {group = "com.vanniktech", name = "emoji-google", version.ref = "vannitechVersion"}
com-google-android-gms-play-services-ads = {group = "com.google.android.gms", name = "play-services-ads", version.ref = "playServicesAdsVersion"}
com-google-firebase-firebase-ads = {group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-ads", version.ref = "firebaseAdsVersion"}
androidx-work-work-runtime = {group = "androidx.work", name = "work-runtime", version.ref = "workRuntimeVersion"}
androidx-preference-preference-ktx = {group = "androidx.preference", name = "preference-ktx", version.ref = "preferenceKTXVersion"}
com-google-android-gms-play-services-maps = {group = "com.google.android.gms", name = "play-services-maps", version.ref = "playServicesMapsVersion"}
com-google-firebase-firebase-auth = {group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-auth", version.ref = "firebaseAuthVersion"}
androidx-annotation = {group = "androidx.annotation", name = "annotation", version.ref = "annotationVersion"}
androidx-lifecycle-lifecycle-livedata-ktx = {group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-livedata-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleLiveDataKTXVersion"}
androidx-lifecycle-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx = {group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleViewModelKTXVersion"}
com-google-firebase-firebase-database = {group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-database", version.ref = "firebaseDatabaseVersion"}
com-google-firebase-firebase-functions = {group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-functions", version.ref = "firebaseFunctionsVersion"}
androidx-wear = {group = "androidx.wear", name = "wear", version.ref = "wearVersion"}
androidx-viewpager = {group = "androidx.viewpager2", name = "viewpager2", version.ref = "viewpager2Version"}
com-github-MikeOrtiz = {group = "com.github.MikeOrtiz", name = "TouchImageView", version.ref = "touchImageViewVersion"}
com-google-firebase-firebase-bom = {group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-bom", version.ref = "firebaseBOMVersion"}
com-google-firebase-firebase-analytics = {group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-analytics", version.ref = "firebaseAnalyticsVersion"}
com-google-firebase-firebase-messaging = {group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-messaging", version.ref = "firebaseMessagingVersion"}
com-google-firebase-firebase-appcheck-debug = {group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-appcheck-debug", version.ref = "firebaseAppcheckVersion"}
com-google-firebase-firebase-appcheck-playintegrity = {group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-appcheck-playintegrity", version.ref = "firebaseAppcheckVersion"}
com-firebaseui-firebase-ui-database = {group = "com.firebaseui", name = "firebase-ui-database", version.ref = "firebaseUIDatabasse"}
com-firebaseui-firebase-ui-auth = {group = "com.firebaseui", name = "firebase-ui-auth", version.ref = "firebaseUIAuth"}
com-google-android-material-material = {group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "materialVersion"}
com-google-gms-play-services-gcm = {group = "com.google.android.gms", name = "play-services-gcm", version.ref = "playServicesGCMVersion"}
com-android-volley = {group = "com.android.volley", name = "volley", version.ref = "volleyVersion"}
com-google-android-gms = {group = "com.google.android.gms", name = "play-services-location", version.ref = "playServicesLocationVersion"}
androidx-mutidex = {group = "androidx.multidex", name = "multidex", version.ref = "multidexVersion"}
com-google-android-libraries-maps = {group = "com.google.android.libraries.maps", name = "maps", version.ref = "mapsVersion"}
androidx-biometrics = {group = "androidx.biometric", name = "biometric", version.ref = "biometricVersion"}
com-google-auto-value-annotations = {group = "com.google.auto.value", name = "auto-value-annotations", version.ref = "autoValueAnnotationsVersion"}
com-google-maps-android = {group = "com.google.maps.android", name = "android-maps-utils", version.ref = "androidMapsUtilsVersion"}
com-google-code-json = {group = "com.google.code.gson", name = "gson", version.ref = "gsonVersion"}
com-anroidmapsextension = {group = "com.androidmapsextensions", name = "android-maps-extensions", version.ref = "androidMapsExtensionVersion"}
androidx-work = {group = "androidx.work", name = "work-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "workRuntimeKTXVersion"}
androidx-room-room-gradle-plugin = {group = "androidx.room", name = "room-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "roomGradlePluginVersion"}
androidx-room-room-ktx = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-ktx", version.ref = "roomVersion" }
androidx-room-room-runtime = {group = "androidx.room", name = "room-runtime", version.ref = "roomRuntimeVersion"}
androidx-sqlite = {group = "androidx.sqlite", name = "sqlite-ktx", version.ref = "sqliteKTXVeresion"}
kotlinx-coroutines-android = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android", version.ref = "kotlinxCoroutinesAndroid" }
kotlinx-coroutines-core = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core", version.ref = "kotlinxCoroutinesCore" }
materialdrawer = { module = "com.mikepenz:materialdrawer", version.ref = "materialdrawer" }
net-zetic-android-database-sqlcipher = {group = "net.zetetic", name = "android-database-sqlcipher", version.ref = "sqlcipherAndroidVersion"}

net-zetic-sqlcipher-android  = {group = "net.zetetic", name = "sqlcipher-android", version.ref = "sqlcipherAndroidVersion"}
androidx-lifecycle-runtime = {group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleVersion"}
org-jetbrains-kotlin-multiplatform = {group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name = "multiplatform", version.ref = "kotlinMultiplatformVersion"}
com-google-gms-google-services = {group = "com.google.gms", name = "google-services", version.ref = "googleServicesVersion"}
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtxVersion" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCoreVersion" }
androidx-room-room-compiler = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-compiler", version.ref = "devToolsKSPVersion" }
play-services-ads-v2320 = { module = "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads", version.ref = "playServicesAds" }
symbol-processing-api = { module = "com.google.devtools.ksp:symbol-processing-api", version.ref = "symbolProcessingApi" }
wearable = { module = "com.google.android.wearable:wearable", version.ref = "wearable" }


[plugins]
androidApplication = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
androidLibrary = { id = "com.android.library", version.ref = "agp" }
kotlinAndroid = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlinMultiplatform = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlinCocoapods = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.cocoapods", version.ref = "kotlin" }
org-jetbrains-kotlin-android = {id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref =  "kotlinVersion"}
androidx-room = {id = "androidx.room", version.ref = "androidRoomVersion"}
org-jetbrains-kotlin-multiplatform = {id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform", version.ref = "kotlinMultiplatformVersion"}
com-android-application = {id =  "com.android.application", version.ref = "androidGradlePluginVersion"}
com-google-gms-google-services = {id = "com.google.gms.google.services", version.ref = "googleServicesVersion"}
org-jetbrains-kotlin-jvm = {id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm", version.ref = "kotlinVersion"}
compose-compiler = {id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose", version.ref = "kotlinVersion"}
com-google-devtools-ksp-gradle-plugin = {id = "com.google.devtools.ksp.gradle.plugin", version.ref = "devToolsGradlePluginVersion" }
com-google-devtools-ksp = {id = "com.google.devtools.ksp",  version.ref =  "devToolsGradlePluginVersion" }





Please remove all dependencies from the "iosMain.dependencies" block.

Remove this block
iosMain.dependencies {
    val composeBom =
        project.dependencies.platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.06.00")
    implementation(composeBom)
    implementation  (libs.compose.ui)
}


The references to compose in commonMain are sufficient.
